# Django authentication system

Tags: python, django, authentication, redirect

i'm using  the django built in authentication system and in my login template  i have this code :

login.html:

```
{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h2>Login</h2>
{% if user.is_authenticated%}
    you are already logged in
  {% else %}
  <form method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

but what i really want to do is to redirect  the user to the home page if he tries to access login page  while  already logged in, but i am new to django so i don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For django>=1.11 you can set redirect_authenticated_user parameter to True in its url in url_patterns to do the redirect, like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='login'),
]
```

read the [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) for more information.

and also set LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in your setting file to your index url or its name:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/index/'
```

Comment: i have this Error :module 'django.contrib.views' has no attribute 'LoginView'

Comment: you should import it form `django.contrib.auth.views` not `django.contrib.views`

Comment: it says :can not import name 'vews' from django.contrib.auth.views

Comment: it's the same built-in class that you said you are using it just set that parameter to True in it.

Comment: i have to point out  that i have two apps: a blog app  and an account app  i use  the account app for login and sign up  but the login template  is in the blog app :blog>templates>registration>login.html i dont know i f this config can cause an error

Comment: it will not cause any problem. but it's recommended to put the templates in a global templates directory within your Django project.

Comment: your code worked  but i had  to upgrade django version to 2.1, thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your `settings.py' add this:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'index'
```

if the url name of your index is 'index', else put the correct url name

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in your views.py file.

```
def login(request):
    if request.method =="get":
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return render(// youre code)
```

Comment: ,i am using django built in auth views , the login view already exists